# How to use setInterval to enlarge image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve when an image is clicked then it will enlarge for a set amount of time. So far I'm up to here in my JS but it doesn't work

```
 var image =  document.getElementById('pic');

function enlarge() {
    image.style.height="600px";
}

image.onclick =enlarge;
```

After I tried to implement.

```
 var image =  document.getElementById('pic');

function enlarge() {
    image.style.height="600px";
}

image.onclick = setInterval(enlarge; 1000);
```

How should I implement this? [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pkq3dyra/2/)

Comment: Do you mean you want an animation that takes a while, or do you want the enlarged image to go back to the original after a while?

Comment: @NimrodArgov yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using setInterval**

We want 60fps, so each frame would be 1000 / 60 which equals about 16.667ms long. We need to enlarge the height by `500px`. 500 / 60 equals to 8.334. So we need an interval of `16.667` ms, and every iteration, enlarge the image by `8.334px`, and stop when the height reaches `600px`:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.pic');

images.forEach(function(image) {
  image.addEventListener('click', enlarge);
});

function enlarge(e) {
  var image = e.target;
  var interval;
  var height = 100;
  
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    height += 8.334;
    
    if(height >= 600) {
      height = 600;
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    image.style.height = height + 'px';
  }, 16.667);
}
```

```css
.pic {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://placehold.it/100x100' class='pic'>
<img src='https://placehold.it/100x100' class='pic'>
```

---

**Using requestAnimationFrame**

A better way of doing it, will use [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) that produces smoother animations. According to MDN:

> The window.requestAnimationFrame() method tells the browser that you
>   wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser call a
>   specified function to update an animation before the next repaint.

The math stays the same, but requestAnimationFrame will handle the calling the next frame after 16.667ms.

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.pic');

images.forEach(function(image) {
  image.addEventListener('click', enlarge);
});

function enlarge(e) {
  var image = e.target;
  var interval;
  var height = 100;
  
  function enlargeInner() {
    height += 8.334;
    
    if(height >= 600) {
      height = 600;
    }
    
    image.style.height = height + 'px';
    
    height < 600 && requestAnimationFrame(enlargeInner);
  }
  
  enlargeInner();
}
```

```css
.pic {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://placehold.it/100x100' class='pic'>
<img src='https://placehold.it/100x100' class='pic'>
```

Comment: Im trying to animate it using setInterval

Comment: How do you link this if im using a separate JS file instead of putting this script to a single HTML page?

Comment: It should still work the same, but you might want to user `image.addEventListener('click', enlarge);` instead of binding the event using `onclick=`.

Comment: what if i want the width to be increase also do i just add width += 7.9365; as well?

Comment: I've updated the calculations a bit to fit 60fps. See edit. About the width, just divide the difference between the new and old width by 60. For example, from 100px to 400px, you'll have 300 / 60  = 5. So width would be width += 5.

Comment: One last thing, If i were to have multiple images how should i implement `image.style.height = height + 'px';`

Comment: As long as the `height` variable is inside a function each image will be resized separately. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

You just assign same height in an interval. You need to increment it, like:

```
image.style.height = (+image.style.height + 600) + "px";
```

But I guess it is not your goal, as it will make your image grow `600px` every second. I think what you are looking for is just making it bigger to actual point of size? If so, try using CSS `transition` combined with javascript, like:

**CSS:**

```
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
  transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
}
.enlarged {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('pic').addEventListener("click", function(e){
  this.classList.toggle("enlarged");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

setInterval() only won't work.

Basically what your code is doing, that it waits 1000 milliseconds, and runs the enlarge function.

(by the way, you have a typo, at the last line, there should be a comma between enlarge and 1000)

The way I would do it is to add a css class with an animation, and then add that class to the image on click.

```js
let myImg = document.getElementById("img1");
myImg.addEventListener("click", () => myImg.classList.toggle("enlarge"));


/*

The code above is using ES6 (the newest version of JavaScript) and and a thing called an arrow function. If you don't get it, here is the "normal way" to do it. It will do exactly the same as the above code.

var myImg = document.getElementById("img1");
myImg.addEventListener("click", function(){
  myImg.classList.toggle("enlarge")
});


*/
```

```css
#img1 {
  transition: 1s
}
.enlarge {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="https://foswiki.org/pub/Support/Glossary/600px-Example.svg.png" width="100px" height="100px">
```

Answer (score 0):

I [forked your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p72uzw3a/1).

You need to change the way you're approaching the click event like so:

```
function enlarge() {
  setInterval(function() {
    // do stuff
  }, 1000)
}

image.onclick = enlarge;
```